# Java File System: UNC path is missing sharename

Tags: java

I have a situation to access a shared folders.
Following is a sample java program.

```
import java.nio.file.*;

/**
 * Test
 */
public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String strPath = "//WG0202";
    Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(strPath).getRoot();
    if (path != null)
    {
      System.out.println(path.toFile().exists());
    }
  }
}
```

Let us assume as below -
Computer name: `WG0202`

A folder shared in this computer is: `TestFolder`

So if I give the path as: //WG0202/TetFolder

Then it works fine.

But if I give the path as: //WG0202

Then it is failing with the below exception -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: UNC path is missing sharename: //WG0202
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:118)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
```

Comment: I do not believe Windows SMB will allow you to share a "root" like that.  In essence, what I am trying to say is, I do not believe in the SMB protocol there is a concept of a share without a path.  I believe, in Windows, when you do that it triggers an SMB call to list the available shares.  In your test code, you are relying on the Operating system, which from the context seems to be Windows, to handle the connection to the remote host.  The feature you are trying to rely on is probably written into Windows Explorer and not the base OS.  Just a hunch, though.

Comment: Yes, It is Windows OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Official Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) of File

> User interfaces and operating systems use system-dependent *pathname
>   strings* to name files and directories. This class presents an
>   abstract, system-independent view of hierarchical pathnames. An
>   *abstract pathname* has two components:
>
> 1. **An optional system-dependent *prefix* string, such as a disk-drive specifier, `"/"`for the UNIX root directory, or `"\\\\"` for a Microsoft
>      Windows UNC pathname**, and
> 2. A sequence of zero or more string names.
>
> The
>   first name in an abstract pathname may be a directory name or, in the
>   case of Microsoft Windows UNC pathnames, a hostname. Each subsequent
>   name in an abstract pathname denotes a directory; the last name may
>   denote either a directory or a file. The empty abstract pathname has
>   no prefix and an empty name sequence.

Comment: If it happened to give that hostname as above, then should we supposed to get the exception?

Answer (score 4):

An UNC path is indeed made out of a host and a share. 
You are trying to use UNC without a share, as your exception states.

To clarify:

```
//WG0202/TestFolder
```

is a valid UNC path:

```
//WG0202/
```

is not.

Cheers