# Paths.get on Windows

Tags: java

Consider a method starting like this:

```
private void writeFile(String dir, String name) {
    Path path = Paths.get(dir, name);
    // create & write to file, etc...
```

Now the caller of this method might want to create the file in a specified directory, such as one of the following:

1. <kbd>"C:\path\to\dir"</kbd>  absolute path on specified drive
2. <kbd>"path\to\dir"</kbd> relative path
3. <kbd>"\path\to\dir"</kbd> absolute path on current drive
4. <kbd>"C:\"</kbd> root directory of specified drive
5. <kbd>"\"</kbd> root directory of current drive

The problem is that the last one (i.e. `Paths.get("\\", "x.txt")`) gives the following error:

**Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: UNC path is missing sharename: \\x.txt**

Would this be considered a bug? If not, how would you create a file in the root of the current drive in Windows?

Comment: `Path getRoot();` maybe

Comment: Yeah, I'd consider that a bug. Workaround: `Paths.get("\\").resolve("x.txt")` or `Paths.get("\\.", "x.txt").normalize()`

Comment: [Seems relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611779/java-file-system-unc-path-is-missing-sharename)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, I'd consider that a bug.

If you look at the code for `WindowsFileSystem.getPath(String paramString, String... paramVarArgs)`, you'll find this code (jdk1.8.0_51, source of WindowsFileSystem not included, so this is from disassembler):

```
public final Path getPath(String paramString, String... paramVarArgs)
{
  String str1;
  if (paramVarArgs.length == 0) {
    str1 = paramString;
  } else {
    StringBuilder localStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    localStringBuilder.append(paramString);
    for (String str2 : paramVarArgs) {
      if (str2.length() > 0) {
        if (localStringBuilder.length() > 0)
          localStringBuilder.append('\\');
        localStringBuilder.append(str2);
      }
    }
    str1 = localStringBuilder.toString();
  }
  return WindowsPath.parse(this, str1);
}
```

The code adds `\` between elements, even if preceding element already ends with a `\`, relying on `a\\b` to be compacted to `a\b` in the `WindowsPath.parse()` method.

So, `get("\\", "x.txt")` becomes `\\x.txt`, and two `\` at the beginning is a UNC path, so `parse()` fails.

Suggestion, if you want to file a bug. Change code to:

```
      if (str2.length() > 0) {
        if (localStringBuilder.length() > 0) {
          char c = localStringBuilder.charAt(localStringBuilder.length() - 1);
          if (c != '\\' && c != '/')
            localStringBuilder.append('\\');
        }
        localStringBuilder.append(str2);
      }
```